# How can I create borders between elements in a Flexbox container?

Tags: css

I am trying to replicate this [image: Flex container elements]

I have gotten the flex items all aligned to each other but no matter what I do, I just can't seem to get the short dash border between elements and the bigger white background underneath it. This is my code:

```css
.flex-container {
  border: 5px solid white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  flex-grow: -0.5;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <form class="flex">
    <input class="flex-item" type="date" name="" id="">
    <input class="flex-item" type="text" placeholder="1 NIGHT">
    <input class="flex-item" type="date" name="" id="">
    <input class="flex-item" type="text" placeholder="ALL HOTELS">
    <input class="flex-item" type="text" name="" placeholder="PROMO CODE">
    <input class="flex-item" type="submit" value="CHECK AVAILABILITY">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a `2px` wide element in between them? There are more elegant ways but in the case of inputs i'm not so sure

Answer (score 2):

Chinomso! Below are JUST the changes that I made to the stylesheet, and I commented out the border you used for .flex-container...I included comments next to each line for ease. See if this works!

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* See the Mozilla Developer Network on the box-sizing CSS property,
                               could help here...styling below for margins/border
                               is dependent on this */
}

.flex-container {
    /* border: 5px solid white; */
    padding: 1.5em; /* OPTIONAL - gives the whole container spacing for visual appeal */
  }

  .flex-item {
    border: none; /* Removes the default CSS styling for the <input> HTML tag in browsers */
    border-right: 2px solid black; /* Creates border to right of each .flex-item class */
    text-align: center; /* OPTIONAL - styling to center input text */
    margin: 0 5px; /* OPTIONAL - gives you spacing for visual appeal */
  }

  .flex-item:last-child {
      border: none; /* Remove border from the last .flex-item child in the form */
  }
```

MDN link to article about the CSS "box-sizing" property, has saved my buns plenty of times:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

...

...AND Here is the result I got from adding the above styles to your existing ones:

[image: CSS styles added to create borders for flex container]

Comment: You can simplify like `.flex-item + .flex-item { border-left: 2px solid black; }` no need to select the last child alone

Comment: Thanks. I have been stuck on this for the past two hours. What of the button? How could I get it aligned to the promo code?

Comment: remove last element padding @ChinomsoJohnson

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is just one last thing. How do I create a surrounding white background container for the flex elements just as shown in the picture above?